# Why the SQL query does not match the variable

Tags: php, mysqli

In the UPDATE SQL query in the WHERE field, the variable is incorrectly compared.
If you replace the "WHERE" field with this option, the code works:

```
WHERE `Id` = "1"
```

`Main` Table:

- `Group_IDGroup` (int) 1
- `Human_IDHuman` (int) 1
- `Month_IDMonth` (int) 1
- `DayID` (int) 1
- `Pos` (int) 0
- `Id`  (int) 1

========================================================================

I tried to change the number and position of all characters, for example

```
$result[Id]
$result["Id"]
"$result["Id"]"
\"$result[\"Id\"]\"
".$result["Id"]."
```

Here is a whole piece of code that doesn't work.

```
$sqlchk = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `Group_IDGroup`, `Human_IDHuman`, `Month_IDMonth`, `DayID`, `Pos`, `Id` FROM `Main`');
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlchk)
$query = 'UPDATE `main` SET `Pos` = "!Pos" WHERE (`Id` = "$result[Id]")';
$sqlposchk = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out the statemetn to see if the value for the id is as you expected?

Comment: Yes, when displaying fields completely coincide.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Right answer:

```
$query = "UPDATE `main` SET `Pos` = !Pos WHERE (`Id` = '{$result['Id']}')";
```

Comment: It is not for long. this query will break soon as well. For the Goodness sake, learnabout prepared statements.

Comment: I have been learning php + sql for just a week, for now this is enough.

Comment: Where have you been learning PHP like this? YourCommonSense has great tutorial about PHP https://phpdelusions.net